# How do I reset my calculator, when I enter "$" to input , instead of a number , python

Tags: python, calculator, reset, try-except

I need to reset this calculator when user enter "$" instead first or second input number or user enter "`$`" end of the input number (ex: `5$`,`20$`).

the `(a,b)` is input number1 and number2. it was assigned as global varibles.

`select_op(choice)` is function, running the operation that user need. `input_function()` is function for input two numbers.

```
# Functions for arithmetic operations.


def add(a,b):
    return (a+b)        # 'a' and 'b' will add.

def subtract(a,b):
    return (a-b)        # 'b' substract from 'a'.

def multiply(a,b):
    return (a*b)        #'a' multiply by 'b'.

def divide(a,b):
    if b == 0 :         .
        return None
    else:
        return (a/b)    # 'a' divided by 'b'.

def power(a,b):
    return (a**b)       # 'a' power of 'b'.

def remainder(a,b):
    if b == 0:           
        return None
    else:
        return (a%b)    # reminder of 'a' divided by 'b'.


#this function for out put of operation

def select_op(choice):      #this function will select operation
    if choice == "+":
        input_function()
        print(a,' + ',b,' = ',add(a,b))
    elif choice == "-":
        input_function()
        print(a,' - ',b,' = ',subtract(a,b))
    elif choice == "*":
        input_function()
        print(a,' * ',b,' = ',multiply(a,b))
    elif choice == "/":
        input_function()
        if b==0:                            
            print("float division by zero")
        print(a,' / ',b,' = ',divide(a,b))
    elif choice == "^":
        input_function()
        print(a,' ^ ',b,' = ',power(a,b))
    elif choice == "%":
        input_function()
        if b==0:                           
            print("float division by zero")
        print(a,' % ',b,' = ',remainder(a,b))
    elif choice == "#":                    #if choice is '#' program will terminate.
        return -1
    elif choice == "$":                    #if choice is '$' program reset.
        return None
    else:
        print("Unrecognized operation")



#this function for input two operands.
def input_function():
    number1=float(input("Enter first number: "))
    number2=float(input("Enter second number: "))
    global a,b
    a=number1
    b=number2
    return a,b


#loop repeat until user need to terminate.


while True:
  print("Select operation.")
  print("1.Add      : + ")
  print("2.Subtract : - ")
  print("3.Multiply : * ")
  print("4.Divide   : / ")
  print("5.Power    : ^ ")
  print("6.Remainder: % ")
  print("7.Terminate: # ")
  print("8.Reset    : $ ")


  # take input from the user
  choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
  print(choice)


  if(select_op(choice) == -1):
    #program ends here
    print("Done. Terminating")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check whether the string returned from `input()` ends with a "$" ***before*** converting it to a `float`.

To reset when a user types something that ends with "$", you could throw an exception to break out of your calculator logic and start over. We'll surround the stuff inside your while loop with a `try`/`catch`, so that the exception doesn't stop your program, but merely starts a new iteration in the while loop.

```py
# I omitted all your other functions at the start of the file
# but of course those should be included as well

class ResetException(Exception):
    pass

#this function for input two operands.
def input_function():
    s = input("Enter first number: ")
    if s.endswith("$"):
        raise ResetException()
    number1=float(s)
    s = input("Enter second number: ")
    if s.endswith("$"):
        raise ResetException()
    number2=float(s)
    global a,b
    a=number1
    b=number2
    return a,b


#loop repeat until user need to terminate.


while True:
  print("Select operation.")
  print("1.Add      : + ")
  print("2.Subtract : - ")
  print("3.Multiply : * ")
  print("4.Divide   : / ")
  print("5.Power    : ^ ")
  print("6.Remainder: % ")
  print("7.Terminate: # ")
  print("8.Reset    : $ ")


  # take input from the user
  try:
    choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
    print(choice)

    if(select_op(choice) == -1):
      #program ends here
      print("Done. Terminating")
      exit()
  except ResetException:
    pass
```